# BitmapImage cannot access the file

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, ioerror

In my current project, I need to download the file from the Internet once and use them in my WPF application later. I've set up this lazy loading pattern in order to download/initialize `BitmapImage` only when requested by application, but despite my utmost effort, I can't get it to work. The problem is that I get `IOException` when it tries to instantiate `BitmapImage`.

Below I post a complete application, that you can run yourself and arrive the same problem...

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        string url = @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d3/Nelumno_nucifera_open_flower_-_botanic_garden_adelaide2.jpg";
        string filename = "PrettyFlower.jpg";
        Mutex m = new Mutex();
        bool isLoaded = false;
        BitmapImage flowerImage = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Binding b = new Binding("FlowerImage");
            b.Source = this;
            img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, b);
        }

        public BitmapImage FlowerImage 
        {
            get
            {
                if (isLoaded == false)
                {
                    LoadImage();
                    return null;
                }
                return flowerImage;
            }
        }

        private async void LoadImage()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            m.WaitOne();

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
            if (fi.Exists == false)
            {
                await wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync(url, filename);
            }

            flowerImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/" + filename));
            isLoaded = true;
            OnPropertyChanged("FlowerImage");

            m.ReleaseMutex();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And corresponding MainWindow.xaml is nothing more but:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Image x:Name="img"/>
</Window>
```

I do notice whats going on, but honestly I don't understand why is this happening - that is, `BitmapImage` is instantiated before the download completes, but shouldn't mutex here prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got this to work finally, and it is not like Clemens said.. :(

The problem seems to be ... (and I believe it is) that LoadImage doesn't start another thread until it calls `wc.DownloadFileTaskAsync`. This is the only thing that runs in another thread, therefore... the call to `WaitOne()` is completly silly, since mutex is claimed by UI thread ...

The way I got it to work is...

```
private async void LoadImage()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();

            await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    m.WaitOne();

                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
                    if (fi.Exists == false)
                    {
                        wc.DownloadFile(url, filename);
                        wc.Dispose();
                    }

                    m.ReleaseMutex();
                });

            m.WaitOne();
            flowerImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/" + filename));
            m.ReleaseMutex();

            isLoaded = true;
            OnPropertyChanged("FlowerImage");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't use a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this. Instead use a plain file URI that references the downloaded file (where `filename` is the full path as in your code):

```
flowerImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename));
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I get it... Am I not referencing the downloaded file as it with "pack://siteOfOrigin:,,,/" + filename? Like, I thought that this is the problem :/